# Custom Java XMLBuilder vs Standard classes-based

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

What is the best performance solution for XML generation.

My goal is to build a few simple XMLs from code. I am going to implement simple custom StringBuffer based implementation of XML Builder. From other side there are several libraries like http://code.google.com/p/java-xmlbuilder/ and http://code.google.com/p/xmltool/ which has nice DSL but I guess lack on performance.

Since my goal is build simple enough XMLBuilder with great performance I think I will build custom solution. It will featuring:

- Nice Java-based DSL for XML constructs (adding tags basically)
- Great StringBuffer based performance.
- String data escape handling when adding XML tags.
- Auto-indent

Please suggest if I am wrong on performance expectations and its probably better to use ready-made libraries.

**UPDATE.** Why I think the performance of standard xml builders is not very good.

Standard XML builders uses Document Builder Factory and works with classes behind the scenes. Also these classes optimized to fit all users. For example I don't need namespace support etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<root>
 <testdata>value</testdata>
</root>
</xml>
```

Consider very simple XML code above. If you build with standard tools it will involve so many work just to make this simple XML. I consider that it's better to just generate it by myself using String.

**UPDATE 2**. Performance requirement is that code should do as many things as required to generate simple XML and not more.

**UPDATE 3. Thanks** everyone for great comments! Now I understand better what I need and that my initial goal was not set very correctly with word "performance". My true goal is to use simple enough solution with convenient DSL to describe the XML structure and generate the XML output.

I will use plain Java objects as DSL for XML and generate XML using XStream library which is pretty straightforward solution.

**UPDATE 4. JAXB.** I discussed XStream vs JAXB and found that JAXB is faster than XStream. Plus I already use JAXB in my project and I like its standard annotations. I change my mind and will go with JAXB for now because XStream was originally heavily developed at the time when JAXB was not so good as today.

Comment: What's DSL? what does it stand for?

Comment: @Elite: Domain-Specific Language

Comment: What is your performance requirement? Even if its a bit slower, it is likely to be fast enough.  Performance isn't the only criteria which chosing a solution.

Comment: More important, your solution using a StringBuilder (StringBuffer is so 1990s) is almost guaranteed to be **broken**. In other words, it will occasionally produce output that a conforming XML parser will reject. There's more to building XML than "escape handling."

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Good question about performance requirement. I posted Update to explain. In short words my performance requirement is that code should do as many things as required to generate simple XML and not more.

Comment: @Anon, What do you think is needed more to build XML than simple espace handling and maintaing correct structure?

Comment: @Vladimir, for your approach to be highly performant, you must be able to begin streaming out the result before you are finished generating the XML.  Also note that if you keep the whole result in memory, it might scale badly.

Comment: Well, let's start with encoding. You're generating output as a string, so how will you deal with converting that string to bytes? There are dozens of such seemingly minor points that are buried in the XML spec. But looking at your comments, you seem determined to go your own way, so I suppose that in a few weeks we'll get to hear from someone who is trying and failing to parse your XML with a standard parser, and wants to know how to parse with regexes.

Comment: @Vladmir, So your aim is for the simplest solution?  The simplest is likely to be the best, though it is the more complex solutions which tend to be more performant.

Comment: To limit your code to do not more than required you need to have a good understanding of what assumptions you can make. e.g. do you need characters at all, can you use just bytes? I suggest you test your output using a standard parser to so that your output can be read by a generic parser.

Comment: Regarding update 3, check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan, Thank you. I've sent you a question by email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest something very controversial but still ...

**Make profiling and performance tests** with both libraries.

If you don't have time for that, assuming something is slow would be the wrong choice in my opinion.
Because if it turns out that it actually is not slow, it would save you a lot of time to use an already built and supported library/framework.

Another thought.
You will need to test your completed high performance solution against the solutions already available anyway, to check if it is really high performance. So I would strongly suggest measuring the performance of the libraries available before starting your own.

Comment: I agree with you, but as you mentioned I don't have time for that. I should choose solution based on existent experience. Once I pick right way I will not go for other ways even if they will be slightly better.

Comment: @Vladimir, if you do not have time for analyzing, you do not have time for coding either.  Go for a solution where you generate SAX-events to a Transformer generating your result.

Comment: @Vladimir you might end up loosing time if you don't test them. You might not be able to choose on existing experience if you don't have it, which is currently the case with these 2 libraries. If I can make an analogy, it would be that you currently have options A, B and C. You are going for option C without knowing what options A and B are. Which might end up hurting you. If you don't have time to check then go with either since there is now way to know if that is the right choice.

Comment: I can only say that I agree with previous comments -- if you do not know current performance, or what you want, it is likely you will spend time writing code that either does not work well, or is no faster, or quite possibly, both. Testing need not take very long; if you have done performance testing before it really is quite easy to try out.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding:

> Standard XML builders uses Document
>   Builder Factory and works with classes
>   behind the scenes. Also these classes
>   optimized to fit all users. For
>   example I don't need namespace support
>   etc.

An alternative to DOM is StAX ([JSR-173](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173)).  It is a Streaming API for XML that is quite fast.  There are several implementations, I have found [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) to be quite performant.

Comment: thank you for this answer quite appreciate. I slightly rethought my goal into direction of more simple and convenient solution rather than more performant.

Comment: No problem.  I'll admit my bias upfront that I lead the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation.  But JAXB is the standard for object to XML mapping (several implementations:  Metro, MOXy, JaxMe, etc).  In your question you made a big point about performance, and XStream (like all XML serializers) have a performance hit because there is no upfront initialization time.  Google and check out my blog for more info:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: great to hear from you. I am checking your blog know. By the way I was using TopLink 5 years later - nice API comparing to Hibernate :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is powerful and flexible Groovy's NodeBuilder (http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyMarkup).

```
def root = new NodeBuilder()
  .people(kind:'folks', groovy:true) {
    person(x:123,  name:'James', cheese:'edam') {
      project(name:'groovy')
      project(name:'geronimo')
    }
    person(x:234,  name:'bob', cheese:'cheddar') {
      project(name:'groovy')
      project(name:'drools')
    }
  }
XmlUtil.serialize(root, System.out)
```

This results with an XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people kind="folks" groovy="true">
  <person x="123" name="James" cheese="edam">
    <project name="groovy"/>
    <project name="geronimo"/>
  </person>
  <person x="234" name="bob" cheese="cheddar">
    <project name="groovy"/>
    <project name="drools"/>
  </person>
</people>
```

Comment: It looks, though, like it would build a DOM tree equivalent in memory, and only then write out. This means performance of DOM-based output as well as memory limitations.

Answer (score 1):

One more high-performance suggestion: use [StaxMate](http://staxmate.codehaus.org) -- it is as fast as underlying Stax-based XML writer, which is rather fast (40 - 80 megabytes per second, sustained). Just make sure you do NOT use default JDK 6 Stax implementation (Sun sjsxp) but something faster like Woodstox or Aalto.

I would strongly recommend against writing your own XML writer; it is typically risky (good chance you will forget some part of escaping) as others have mentioned, and not all that likely to be faster than existing **efficient** solutions (not all existing solutions are efficient; you do need to find ones that are). And in the end... unless you really want to write these things, why not work on something more interesting and meaningful?

But if you do want to do something above and beyond existing writers you could consider using a simple writer and augmenting it with additional functionality that you need. For example, if you just use Stax XMLStreamWriter as base, it is quite easy to add simple but efficient abstractions. Or if you like existing packages, see if you can suggest improvements to their authors (or even code contributions).

Answer (score 0):

There is powerful [XmlBuilder](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java)

```java
import com.github.underscore.XmlBuilder;

var xmlBuilder =
    XmlBuilder.create("people")
        .a("kind", "folks")
        .a("groovy", "true")
        .e("person")
        .a("x", "123")
        .a("name", "James")
        .a("cheese", "edam")
        .e("project")
        .a("name", "groovy")
        .a("self-closing", "true")
        .up()
        .e("project")
        .a("name", "geronimo")
        .a("self-closing", "true")
        .up()
        .up()
        .e("person")
        .a("x", "234")
        .a("name", "bob")
        .a("cheese", "cheddar")
        .e("project")
        .a("name", "groovy")
        .a("self-closing", "true")
        .up()
        .e("project")
        .a("name", "drools")
        .a("self-closing", "true");
System.out.println(xmlBuilder.toXml(Xml.XmlStringBuilder.Step.FOUR_SPACES));
```

This results with an XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people kind="folks" groovy="true">
    <person x="123" name="James" cheese="edam">
        <project name="groovy"/>
        <project name="geronimo"/>
    </person>
    <person x="234" name="bob" cheese="cheddar">
        <project name="groovy"/>
        <project name="drools"/>
    </person>
</people>
```